# newb to arduino, how to navigate the ESP8266 vs ESP32 examples and tutorials?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

a big thanks to the many before me creating this space and solving many questions.

I've been learning ESP32 (currently using ESP-WROOM-32 board) while I've found tutorials specific to this board, also finding cool examples built for ESP8266 which are close but using different pins (this I can fix) and different imported libraries (which I'm struggling with).

What's the most complete ESP32 tutorial series you've found?

I'll also be working through similar examples on uno, raspberri pi, so I'm expecting to run into this issue in future. Just curious how others deal with the pedantics of different libraries for different hardware..

any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspberry pi libraries and features are too wide to be covered in one answer. However, I can give you some pointers that helped me a lot.

Most of the programming will be done using Python. Most common libraries can be installed via PIP (the package management for python). You can access all sorts of things: image capture, GPIO, communication protocols and custom libraries.

Most often, you want to automate things on your Pi, two options can be used. You can set a python script as a service ([example here)](http://www.diegoacuna.me/how-to-run-a-script-as-a-service-in-raspberry-pi-raspbian-jessie/) using systemd or you can use a Cronjob (sudo crontab -e) The service run at startup and can run continuously while a Cronjob is scheduled to happen at fixed time interval (example: reboot at midnight...). There are probably other ways to do automation and scheduling, but I found that those were easy enough to use without over-complicating things.

Keep in mind that a Raspberry pi is a different beast compared to the ESP series of micro controller. You get the full access and potential of a Linux platform with a slightly more limited interfacing potential(No readily available analog input/output is probably THE single frustration I had with the Pi). You can always interface another board via some serial protocol.

Regarding the other platforms, it's all about your intended usage. It's hard to point you toward a specific group of libraries. For my narrow usage of esp8266, Sparkfun Electronics tutorials were good enough. For Arduino, it is so widely supported that a simple google search willy yield you exactly what you want (there is also a stackexchange dedicated to that specific platform).

At the end of the day, most libraries are often quite similar and switching from one device to the other become more of a habit than anything else. I know that a lot of Arduino libraries are migrated to ESP platform so they even share common functions that are virtually the same in both platform.

Comment: thanks. not sure how I missed accepting the answer. finally learning how to use SE & SO better.